# Ito integral of $\int_0^t B_{s/2} d B_s$

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

Are the more or less closed formula for Ito integral

$$
\int_0^t B_{s/2} d B_s
$$

where $B_s$ is standard 1-dimensional Brownian motion?

For example, $\int_0^t B_s d B_s = (B_t^2 - t) / 2$, are there similar result for integral above?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Note that $B_{s/2} = \frac{B_s}{\sqrt{2}}$.

Comment: @Abezhiko that's true only in sense that $B_{s/2}$ and $B_{s}/\sqrt{2}$ have same distribution; one can not change random variable under Ito integral like this.